# PHP multi string comparison

Tags: php, string, compare

I want to check if 6 strings are not the same.
I have tried this:

```
if($first != $second != $third != $four != $fifth != $sixth){}
```

but i'm getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL)
```

I don't know any function who can do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (count(array_unique(array($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth)) == 6) {
    echo 'All different';
}
```